# navigate webpage without opening a browser

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write a python script that will check every hour for open seats in the organic chemistry class at my university and email me if it finds one so that I can then log in and register for it (I am not quite good enough to have it register me automatically). I think that I have gotten the login process correct, but when I navigate manually to the correct page to get the URL, it has the same URL as the page before it, which doesn't make much sense. How can I find the correct URL, or if I need to POST, how do I find the right spot and the right commands? Can I navigate within the website without opening a browser, since this will be running hourly in the background while I am trying to use the computer? Unfortunately I cannot share the website, since it contains personal information.

Comment: did you maintained the same session after the first POST request?

Comment: I understand that you can't share the website, but can you share some example code and some screenshots to better help us understand your question? Just based on your description, I suspect that you should probably open up your DevTools and analyze the web requests. Sites like: https://willschenk.com/articles/2019/reverse_engineering_apis_using_chrome/ and https://medium.com/better-practices/reverse-engineering-an-api-403fae885303 might help.

Comment: modern pages use JavaScript to update html and then page may have always the same URL. It would be simpler to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) which can run JavaScript. And with `selenium` you can try to use `DevTool` (tab `Network`, filter `XHR`) in Chrome/Firefox to find out what url was used by JavaScript to get data. And when you get this url then you can try to use it with `requests`. Usually it sends data as JSON which you can easily convert to Python dictionary without scraping HTML using `BeautifulSoup`